# A simple collapsable navigation with Bootstrap 3

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I thought this would be pretty simple, but I've not yet managed to get it to work. The following example looks just like what I want, but it pertains to Bootstrap 2.3. I am having trouble getting it to work in Bootstrap 3. What differences should I be aware of when implementing this for version 3?

http://cssdeck.com/labs/twitter-bootstrap-plain-collapsible-tree-menu

Answer (score 4):

The 2.x example used `nav-list` which has been removed from Bootstrap 3. You can add `nav-list` to 3.x using..

```
.nav-list {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

And, `divider` was replaced with `nav-divider`.

Demo: http://bootply.com/94004

Comment: Thanks! Can you help me understand and/or point me to doc explaining .tree-toggler and .tree?